# How can I update my password in Cisco Jabber without having to reset Jabber?

Tags: instant-messaging

I have changed my password in Cisco Jabber through some non-Android device. I also use Cisco Jabber on Android though. How can I update my password in Cisco Jabber for Android without having to reset Cisco Jabber?

---

After I changed my password in Cisco Jabber, (amazingly) I can still sign in:

[image]

However, instant messaging, phone services and voicemail are not available:

[image]

I know I could reset by  Cisco Jabber application, but I would rather avoid that, since as its name suggests it resets everything:

[image]

Notes:

- after clicking on the sign out button, the user is redirected to screenshot 1, and they can still sign in even without specifying the password. The user isn't asked for the new password, amazingly.
- restarting the Cisco Jabber application or rebooting the phone after signing  out doesn't help.

Comment: On the second screenshot I see a link to "sign out". I'd expect it would allow you to sign-in again with the new password after having properly signed out?

Comment: @Izzy thank you good point I forgot to mention: after clicking on the sign out button, the user is redirected to screenshot 1, and they can still sign in even without specifying the password. The user isn't asked for the new password, amazingly.

Comment: Ah, I already wondered why/how it shows a sign-in page if you hadn't signed out :) Doubt it does the trick, but worth a try: Sign out, close the app, go to the app's page in *Settings › Apps*, force-close it, delete cache, optionally reboot right after that. That *might* make it lose its "token", so it should ask for complete login data on the next try. Again, not sure it does (might have saved that elsewhere) – but worth a try.

Comment: @Izzy restarting the Cisco Jabber application or rebooting the phone after signing  out doesn't help. And it looks like in `Settings › Apps` I don't have the option to remove the cache.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Consider approaching their support: sign-out should sign out, so sign-in then should ask for user *and* password. I'd name that "bug".

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and resolved it by going to Accounts -> Instant Messaging and manually changing my password there.  Then reset the program and when you open it again it should work.